# Contour plot python, how to change labels

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to change what I am labeling. I mean, instead of the values of the levels I would like to write something different. For instance in a plot like the first one in http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html I would like to change 1.500, 1.000, 0.5 for 56%, 34%,23%. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar on these terms:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

##################################################
# Define our surface
##################################################
delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)


CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)

fmt = {}
strs = [ '54%', '10%', '3%', '47%', '51%', '66%', '7%' ]
for l,s in zip( CS.levels, strs ):
    fmt[l] = s

# Label every other level using strings
plt.clabel(CS,CS.levels[::2],inline=True,fmt=fmt,fontsize=10)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Sorry but I do not see how this solves it. I just get another figure with the canvas, but what I want is to change the labels on the contour plot not the values on the y axis, but the values of the countours.

Comment: @florpi I misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer. Check now. What you want to do it to set the custom test to the levels. Hence what you are looking for is: plt.clabel